# BadArgument:Security token not valid for this conversation

Tags: node.js, botframework, botconnector, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to use **Direct Line API** of microsoft bot framework,

Following steps are followed.

1. Got Conversation Id from application(running on node.js)

> [conversationId123]

2. Create Conversation Token from postman
   https://directline.botframework.com/api/tokens/conversation

> [ConversationToken456]

3. Get Conversation Messages using **conversationId123** & Authorization  header using **ConversationToken456**

https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/**conversationId123**/messages

I receive

```
BadArgument:Security token not valid for this conversation
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what's going wrong without seeing the whole flow; though the error indicates that the token is invalid.

Here is a [DirectLine](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine) sample using Node.js. You might want to use it as the baseline for your sample and I'm pretty sure you will find out the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think before sending a message to the BOT you should call the URL stream that returns from the initial "Start conversation" POST request. At least that appears at the [documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/#navtitle)
In my case, using C# I'm able to retrieve a token, then message ID and even request the bot to send me a list of activities, but I'm unable to send a message (the POST request never comes back with an answer)